Usage of というからには in this sentence:
Context: the main character figured the culprit. So he decided to go, alone, at his bar and tell him what he found out:
The culprit then says this
対策課の黒鳥さんは看過できないでしょう。だからこうしていらっしゃった。お一人で
"Of course you can't overlook it, being 対策課. That's why you came here. Alone"
黒鳥の中でも警戒心が膨れあがった。わざわざ一人で、というからには何らかの意図があるはずだ。
逃げるか、それともなかったことに―黒鳥を何らかの方法で消すか。いずれにせよ穏当ではない。
Then the main character narration adds this:
黒鳥の中でも警戒心が膨れあがった。わざわざ一人で、というからには何らかの意図があるはずだ。
"Inside of himself the sense of wariness grows"
What I can't quite make sense of is the nuance of this second part:
わざわざ一人で、というからには何らかの意図があるはずだ。
というからには, is is being used that by intentionally saying 一人で the mastermind is showing he has some kind of plan?

Who is 黒鳥? The main character or a third person?

The main character, the narration is in third/second person

という doesn't necessarily mean vocally saying something. Here, showing he's alone is enough to warrant the use of という(からには).

わざわざ一人で、というからには何らかの意図があるはずだ。
Deliberately coming alone means there must be some intention behind it.


this passage is also using another gramatical point: からには　"given that, judging from"  (N2). So in conjunction you get "Given (からには) the fact (という) s/he is alone, there must be some intention behin it".

I see. My hunch was that given the culprit specifically said  "わざわざ一人で"  the narration was pointing out it like "since he said I came alone..."
